# Junit - Mock for HttpClient Execute

Tags: junit

i have class which has doGet and doPost methods. In that methods am passibg string values and used httpclient.execute method to execute the get or post requests with headers and authentication info.

But i want to write junit for this class, when i try to mock using mocito, am getting only null response.

Please guide me how to add junit with httpclient.execute method.

Comment: Share the code you are trying to test, please.

Answer (score 1):

In my unit test class I do somethig like this:

```
@Mock private HttpClient httpClient;
```

Then for example in `@Before` method create mocks by:

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MyTestClass);
```

Then in a test method you define what `execute()` method should return:

```
when(httpClient.execute(any())).thenReturn(JSON object);
```

You can also try to use PowerMockito. 
Or provide the code to better understand the question.